# Mostrar gráfico chartJS mesmo que não tenha dados

Tags: chartjs

Existe maneira de exibir as colunas do gráfico BarChart do ChartJS, mesmo que não tenham dados para ser exibidos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu vi em diversas bibliotecas, inclusive na do ChartJS, só é possível mostrar a coluna com algum valor, nem que seja valor zero (0).

Pois um gráfico é baseado em valores, logo, se não tem valores, não será mostrado.

Eu fiz um [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DouglasGarrido/ben9ooa3/3/) para exemplificar. Nele eu informo o *array* de *data* com valores zero, assim o gráfico aparece, mas não as colunas. Como eu disse, elas só vão aparecer se tiverem valor.

Comment: Acredito que terei que tratar o array então para trazer os zeros.

Comment: Sim, trate antes de passar para o gráfico.